# Как привязать элементы графического интерфейса к коду?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Хочу из консольного приложения сделать приложение с графическим интерфейсом. 
С помощью *Qt Designer* накидал дизайн, осталось настроить взаимодействие с кодом.

Как привязать `lineEdit` и `lineEdit2` и кнопку `Generate` к моему коду?

```
import random
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("interface01.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()
app.exec()

chars = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM123456789'

number = int(input('Количество паролей: ')) # Сюда привязать данные из lineEdit
lenght = int(input('Длина строки: ')) # Сюда привязать данные из lineEdit_2


for x in range(number):
    password = ''

    for i in range(lenght):
        password += random.choice(chars) # Сюда привязать кнопку Generate
    print(password)

    file = open('password.txt', 'a')
    file.write('\n' + password)
    file.close()
```

[image: картинка интерфейса]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не предоставили модуль **interface01.ui**, почему?

Ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("interface01.ui")

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.chars = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM123456789'
        
        self.number = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Количество паролей')
        self.lenght = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Длина строки')
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("СГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ ПАРОЛЬ", clicked=self.generate_password)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.number)
        layout.addWidget(self.lenght)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)        
        
    def generate_password(self):
        if not self.number.text() or not self.lenght.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 'Заполните входные данные.')
            return
        self.label.setText('')
        for x in range(int(self.number.text())):
            password = ''
            for i in range(int(self.lenght.text())):
                password += random.choice(self.chars)       # Сюда привязать кнопку Generate
            print(password)
            self.label.setText(self.label.text() + f'{password}\n')

            with open('password_1390800.txt', 'a') as file:
                file.write(f'{password}\n')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком виде я могу предоставить модуль  interface01.ui ? Нужен скриншот экрана из QT Desinger ?

Comment: @y3x3la не надо никаких скриншотов.  Это делается точно так как и код `main.py`, который вы успешно опубликовали. Вам что-то не понятно в моем ответе?

Comment: Как добавить возможность курсором выделить сгенерированные пароли ?

Comment: @y3x3la  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.